# Crosswalk error Request Was Denied For Security In Trusted Site

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk

I have done cordova project which is working fine. I have installed crosswalk plugin for making it work in android 4.4 version.I receive a error message when I tried to request to server. Error message is "Request was denied for security". Normally without crosswalk plugin it seems to work fine. But my intention is to make it work in android 4.4.

Answer (score 1):

After one day research find the solution.It's "Intermediate certificate" problem.
We have missed to install intermediate certificate. After installed, now everything is working fine.
Without crosswalk plugin it's work. Because chromium webview automatically installed missing intermediate certificate. But crosswalk  webview doesn't.
The following link will help you to know about certificates details check it out :

https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=

Note : if your server doesn't intermediate certificate it shows broken link